# Python __getitem__ behaviour across different versions

Tags: python, python-2.7, magic-methods

```
class A(object):
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        print item

a = A()
a[0:-1]
```

Output on python 2.7.3, 2.7.7, 2.7.8, 3.3.2 on Windows:

```
slice(0, -1, None)
```

Output on python 2.7.6 (32 bit) on win 32:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: A instance has no attribute '__len__'
```

In python 2.7.6, the slice object tries to get the length of the instance, so that it can convert '-1' to the real value. For example, if the length of the instance is 10, then the output would be 'slice(0, 9, None)'.

This behaviour seems weird. Can anyone verify whether my observation is correct? If it is, then is there any official documentation behind this? How do we cope with this behaviour to support our project on all versions of python?

Comment: If this is the case, then it looks like a bug (which they probably fixed in python2.7.8 ...)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug that got exists somewhere between 2.7.3 and 2.7.8

```
Python 2.7.8 (default, Jul  1 2014, 17:30:21) 
[GCC 4.9.0 20140604 (prerelease)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> class A(object):
...     def __getitem__(self, item):
...         print item
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> a[0:-1]
slice(0, -1, None)
```

Versus

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Feb 27 2014, 19:58:35) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> class A(object):
...     def __getitem__(self, item):
...         print item
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> a[0:-1]
slice(0, -1, None)
```

It may be on Windows.  Go try 2.7.8 on Windows and see if you can reproduce this there.

Comment: Works for Python 2.7.4 (32bit) on Windows.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, it produces the same result on 2.7.8 on windows. The only anomaly is in python 2.7.6